# On Meteor, a function with $inc: is being called twice, when I am attempting to only call it once

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a game in which two people play against each other.  After the clock runs down I call the function below, which is supposed to increase the current question by 1. However, it increases it by 1 TWICE.

```
increaseQuestion: function() {
    GameCollection.update({current:true}, { $inc: { currentQuestion: 1}});
},
```

Here is specifically the code where it is called:

```
Template.gamePage.clock = function () {
    var game = GameCollection.findOne({current: true});
    var currentQuestion = game.currentQuestion;
    var question = game.gameQuestions[currentQuestion];
    var clockQuestion = Clocks.findOne({gameId: game._id, questionId: question._id});
    var clock = clockQuestion.clock;

    if(clock === 0) {
        Meteor.call('increaseQuestion');
    } else {
        Meteor.call('windDown', clockQuestion, clock);
    }

    // format into M:SS
    var min = Math.floor(clock / 60);
    var sec = clock % 60;
    return min + ':' + (sec < 10 ? ('0' + sec) : sec);
};
```

Here is the method within the code above (which could be causing problems)

```
Meteor.methods({
    windDown: function(clockQuestion, clock) {
        var interval = Meteor.setInterval(function () {

            clock -= 1;

            Clocks.update(clockQuestion._id, {$set: {clock: clock}});

            // end of game
            if (clock === 0) {
                // stop the clock
                Meteor.clearInterval(interval);
                // declare zero or more winners

            }
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Why is the function being called twice?  I tried moving the method from both client and server folder to a server only folder and it is still called twice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised it's only being called twice, to be honest.

The `clock` helper has a dependency on the `ClockQuestion` document which has the same `gameId` as the current game.  However, when that helper is run, the `windDown` method is called, which is going to update that `ClockQuestion` document, which is going to cause the helper to be reactively rerun, which is going to call the `windDown` method again, etc...

To be honest, this sort of control logic really should not be included in a helper function for exactly this reason - it's going to be impossible to control.  `windDown` needs to be called by whatever it is that's making the `gamePage` template render in the first place, or else a `Deps.autorun` block, the reactivity of which you can have much more control over, as opposed to a reactive UI element which is (by design) being managed by Meteor rather than your own app explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

My suspicion is this: `Template.gamePage.clock` uses `GameCollection`, so when that collection is updated, then the function will be re-run reactively.

Since `increaseQuestion` doesn't depend on any arguments from the client, why not just move it to the `// end of game` if block in `windDown`?

Comment: I just attempted that, and it called the function multiple times (3-5).  I believe that is because it is within Meteor.setInterval() which is designed to call the function. Any way to improve the //end of game if block to make this not happen?

Comment: that doesn't make sense. The function in setInterval reduces clock by one every time. So it can't execute the `clock === 0` block more than once.

Comment: I put it as a separate more specific question based on your answer with link below.  I really can't figure out how it is running more than once. I am wondering if I only call it "on click" will it run more than once. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047699/meteor-clearinterval-does-not-stop-the-function-from-running